# Putty connection error but RDC working fine [Windows 7]

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access, putty, rdc

I wanted to establish a RDC from my Windows 7 machine to a remote server (Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4).

I followed and adapted the instructions from:
http://laptops.eng.uci.edu/software-installation/using-linux/how-to-configure-xming-putty

Now my RDC works perfectly, but I get the following error log when I try connecting with Putty:

> 2018-05-08 14:58:00   Connecting to 192.168.20.209 port 22
>
> 2018-05-08 14:58:00    We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
>
> 2018-05-08 14:58:00    Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
>
> 2018-05-08 14:58:00    Using SSH protocol version 2
>
> 2018-05-08 14:58:00    Network error: Software caused connection abort

I cannot connect for sftp transfers with FileZilla, which is actually my main problem since I can connect to my server using RDC

> 15:33:34   Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
>
> 15:33:34   Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
>
> 15:33:34   Error:  Could not connect to server

Any idea how to debug this weird situation ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the fact that the keys generated on the first connection to the server were somehow not stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys.
This is probably due to the RDC connection since it happened after I used it.

Following this guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/, I removed the old keys from the server and reconfigured Openssh server. While connecting to the server using Putty, the keys were shared and now Putty, RDC and Filezilla all work.

Answer (score -2):

Reconfig your OpenSSH Server configuration using command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`

Comment: How is this supposed to help? What do you expect this to do?

Comment: This solution actually worked.